# MySQL 1045 error - access denied - very stubborn

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, macos, mysql-error-1045

I have the following situation trying to start MySQL for my Rails 3 project:

```
> mysql
> SHOW GRANTS for 'root'@'localhost'
ERROR 1044 (42000): Access denied for user ''@'localhost' to database 'mysql'

> mysql -u root -p
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

> mysql -u root
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)

> mysql -u root test
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)

> mysqladmin --no-defaults -u root version
mysqladmin: connect to server at 'localhost' failed
error: 'Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)'

> mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables
120611 05:27:06 mysqld_safe Logging to '/usr/local/mysql/data/SS-iMac.local.err'.
touch: /usr/local/mysql/data/SS-iMac.local.err: Permission denied
120611 05:27:06 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /usr/local/mysql/data
/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqld_safe: line 107: /usr/local/mysql/data/SS-iMac.local.err: Permission denied
rm: /tmp/mysql.sock: Permission denied
/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqld_safe: line 144: /usr/local/mysql/data/SS-iMac.local.err: Permission denied
120611 05:27:06 mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /usr/local/mysql/data/SS-iMac.local.pid ended
/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqld_safe: line 107: /usr/local/mysql/data/SS-iMac.local.err: Permission denied

> sudo mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables
120611 17:04:36 mysqld_safe Logging to '/usr/local/mysql-5.5.25-osx10.6-x86_64/data/SS-iMac.local.err'.
120611 17:04:36 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /usr/local/mysql-5.5.25-osx10.6-x86_64/data
120611 17:06:16 mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /usr/local/mysql-5.5.25-osx10.6-x86_64/data/SS-iMac.local.pid ended
```

I've been reading every Q&A I can find on this topic but I keep running into roadblocks.

---

#### Contents of SS-iMac.local.err

Copies of the following code are being added every 10 seconds.

```
120612 17:12:19 mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /usr/local/var/mysql/SS-iMac.local.pid ended
120612 17:12:29 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /usr/local/var/mysql
120612 17:12:29 [Warning] Setting lower_case_table_names=2 because file system for /usr/local/var/mysql/ is case insensitive
120612 17:12:29 [Warning] One can only use the --user switch if running as root

120612 17:12:29 InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
120612 17:12:29 InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
120612 17:12:29 InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
120612 17:12:29 InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
120612 17:12:29 InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
120612 17:12:29 InnoDB: highest supported file format is Barracuda.
120612 17:12:29  InnoDB: Waiting for the background threads to start
120612 17:12:30 InnoDB: 1.1.8 started; log sequence number 1595675
120612 17:12:30 [Note] Server hostname (bind-address): '0.0.0.0'; port: 3306
120612 17:12:30 [Note]   - '0.0.0.0' resolves to '0.0.0.0';
120612 17:12:30 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '0.0.0.0'.
120612 17:12:30 [ERROR] Can't start server: Bind on TCP/IP port: Address already in use
120612 17:12:30 [ERROR] Do you already have another mysqld server running on port: 3306 ?
120612 17:12:30 [ERROR] Aborting

> ps
 PID TTY           TIME CMD
3497 ttys001    0:00.03 -bash
3506 ttys002    0:00.03 -bash

> mysqladmin shutdown
mysqladmin: connect to server at 'localhost' failed
error: 'Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock' (2)'
Check that mysqld is running and that the socket: '/tmp/mysql.sock' exists!
```

Comment: `sudo mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables`

Comment: What does that logfile say? Is the PID filled? Is another process still running?

Comment: @Konerak I've added the logfile. I've closed every terminal window. How can I check if the PID is filled?

Answer (score -1):

sudo mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables This finally works